# How do I expand a storyboard that shows as a tiny square

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a UICollectionView and cell that I've laid out in my storyboard and after committing, it's somehow become smashed into this tiny little box. It looks and works fine in the app but I want to change something in the cell and well...it's a little hard right now ;)

Any advice here?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

move cursor near the corner of the outer box and drag, there will be an arrow for adjusting size there